# TYPO3: $TCA array ['types'][key] section

Tags: configuration, typo3

I want to know what `;` and the numbers `2-2-2` in this array means

```
'types' => Array (
        '0' => Array('showitem' =>
            'hidden, type;;;;1-1-1,title;;;;2-2-2,short,bodytext;;2;richtext:rte_transform[flag=rte_enabled|mode=ts];4-4-4,
            --div--;LLL:EXT:tt_news/locallang_tca.xml:tt_news.tabs.special, datetime;;;;2-2-2,archivedate,author;;3;; ;;;;2-2-2,
                keywords;;;;2-2-2,sys_language_uid;;1;;3-3-3,
            --div--;LLL:EXT:tt_news/locallang_tca.xml:tt_news.tabs.media, image;;;;1-1-1,imagecaption;;5;;,links;;;;2-2-2,news_files;;;;4-4-4,
            --div--;LLL:EXT:tt_news/locallang_tca.xml:tt_news.tabs.catAndRels, category;;;;3-3-3,related;;;;3-3-3,
            --div--;LLL:EXT:tt_news/locallang_tca.xml:tt_news.tabs.access, starttime,endtime,fe_group,editlock,
            --div--;LLL:EXT:tt_news/locallang_tca.xml:tt_news.tabs.extended,
            '),
```

The reason is I want to add a group behind "news_files". [Link to TCA reference](http://typo3.org/documentation/document-library/core-documentation/doc_core_api/4.0.0/view/4/2/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**[showitem](http://typo3.org/documentation/document-library/core-documentation/doc_core_tca/4.6.0/view/1/3/#id2629047)** consists of fields separated by commas (`,`). Each field is defined by 1-5 arguments separated by semicolons (`;`). The first (mandatory) argument is the field name that can be followed by another 4 extra arguments. The last argument that you are referring to ("2-2-2") is a **[form style code](http://typo3.org/documentation/document-library/core-documentation/doc_core_tca/4.6.0/view/1/6/#id2633668)** which is divided by a hyphen (`-`) into *colorscheme*, *stylescheme* and *borderscheme*.